# "Is there a way to raise an error in ActiveModel::Type::Value?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model - cargo.rb and it has a jsonb attribute "containers". Using the Rails 5 Attribute API in cargo.rb, I have defined the below line in cargo.rb
`attribute :containers, Cargo::Containers::Type.new`

In containers/type.rb, I want to raise an error if the container json does not have proper keys.
But the error raised is being catched.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code and log?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `json-schema gem` for checking if keys and values and proper.